# How to split access and error logs in Parallels Plesk?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, log-files

I have a site in PHP on Apache. Is there a way I can define settings in Parallels Plesk Panel for logging for e.g. it should create log file for each day?
Currently my access_log file size is more than 700MB and error_log file size is more than 500MB.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch on "Log rotation" on domain in Plesk Panel, there are settings for rotation logs "by time" or "by size". I assume that log rotation just not enabled for your web site.